# How to convert each element/observation of a dataframe into a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, element

I have this dataset

```
df = data.frame(x = letters[1:10])
```

I convert it to a list where each element of the dataframe is an element of the created list

```
l= as.list((df[1:10,]))
```

the class of each element is a character

```
class(l[[1]])
```

I want to change the class of each of these elements into dataframe. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `split` on the sequence of rows

```
l <- split(df, seq_len(nrow(df)))
```

-checking

```
> class(l[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"
```